# Displaying the elements inside for loop inline html

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display the elements in thumbnail using bootstrap in a single line but whenever I execute it in a for loop it gets printed in different lines. My code:

```
{% for book in all_books %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dan_Brown_novel)" 
         target="_blank"><img src="{{book.book_cover}}" alt="Book1" 
        style="width:60%">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>{{book.title}} - {{book.author}}</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1 - you don't need a clearfix div if using bootstrap row and columns. Remove that first.

2 - It looks like you're looping around the wrong div. Once you've done point 1, then move the div class row outside the loop.

```html
<div class="row">
{% for book in all_books %}
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dan_Brown_novel)" 
         target="_blank"><img src="{{book.book_cover}}" alt="Book1" 
        style="width:60%">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>{{book.title}} - {{book.author}}</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you repeat `<div class="row">`, try to move your for loop only for `<div class="col-md-2">` like this

`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="clearfix">
  {% for book in all_books %}
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dan_Brown_novel)" 
         target="_blank"><img src="{{book.book_cover}}" alt="Book1" 
        style="width:60%">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>{{book.title}} - {{book.author}}</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>`
```